# To Prove that two given triangles are similar if some conditions are given

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

$P$ is any point within triangle $ABC$. $Q$ is a point outside triangle $ABC$ such that $\angle CBQ = \angle ABP$ and $\angle BCQ = \angle BAP$ . Show that the triangles $PBQ$ and $ABC$ are similar.
Sir here I think that the diagram I formed is not according to question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture is that $BC$ divides $\angle PBQ$ internally.  Then:

[image]

- $\angle QBP+\angle PBA=\angle ABQ=\angle QBC+\angle ABC$ and $\angle CBQ=\angle ABP$ gives $\angle QBP=\angle ABC$.
- From $\angle CBQ=\angle ABP$ and $\angle BCQ=\angle BAP$, you have $\triangle CBQ\sim\triangle ABP$, so $BQ/BP=BC/AB$.

So $\triangle PBQ$ and $\triangle ABC$ are similar (same angle and proportional sides).

---

**Edit**: The thought process that goes with this solution is as follows.  If the conclusion is true, then either $CB$ or $AB$ must divide $\angle PBQ$.  Since the given conditions on angles involve only $\triangle CBQ$ and $\triangle ABP$, it is immediate that the two are similar.  Then the correct mental picture emerges --- you rotate the triangle $ABC$ about point $B$ so ray $BC$ becomes ray $BQ$.  Hence the opening statement "$BC$ divides $\angle PBQ$ internally".  By then there is no need to draw any any pictures.

Comment: Please show the diagram!

Comment: Diagram is not really helpful in this case, but added at your request anyway.